# How to show console log in Kibana back-end?

Tags: kibana, kibana-6

I am new to Kibana and want to debug the back-end to investigate the data work follow.

So I added `NODE_OPTION="--inspect"` in start command and used chrome dev tools to watch followed [this](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) then put some `console.log` and `debugger` into the back-end files. But when it starts, the DevTools Console shows nothing.

Info in CLI when starting:

> Debugger attached.
>
> watching for changes  (1516 files)
>
> Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9230/cba617e6-7963-435d-be45-817dada4fd64
>
> [info][listening] basePath Proxy running at http://192.168.1.93:5609/oze

The file I want to debug:
*src/server/index_patterns/service/lib/field_capabilities/field_capabilities.js*

```
    export async function getFieldCap(call, indices = [], metaFiels = []) {
      const esFieldCaps = await callFieldCapsApi(call, indices);
      const fields = indexBy(readFieldCapsResponse(esFieldCaps), 'name');
      console.log(fields)
      debugger
      ...
    }
```

So anyone can tell me what I was wrong/miss in the setup or something? And how I can console log this kind of information from backend files. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. It's because the program was not executed that function yet. It's my mistake at reading code. And the debug method was right.

Besides that, you have to go to the address: {HOST}:{PORT}/json/list, with {HOST} and {PORT} are config of `inspect` option by default are 127.0.0.1 and 9229 respectively, but Kibana usually change the {PORT}, to get the link to Chrome Dev Tool to debug in "devtoolsFrontendUrl" property.

http://127.0.0.1:9231/json/list

```
[ {
  "description": "node.js instance",
  "devtoolsFrontendUrl": "chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html? 
experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9231/8da1348e-05d8-4e52-9b20-b7d8e205d29f",
  "faviconUrl": "https://nodejs.org/static/favicon.ico",
  "id": "8da1348e-05d8-4e52-9b20-b7d8e205d29f",
  "title": "/home/vndev1/Public/cm-kibana/kibana-6.3.1/src/cli",
  "type": "node",
   "url": "file:///home/vndev1/Public/cm-kibana/kibana-6.3.1/src/cli",
   "webSocketDebuggerUrl": "ws://127.0.0.1:9231/8da1348e-05d8-4e52-9b20-b7d8e205d29f"
 } ]
```